# Create Many-to-One relationship between tables in db MVC 3 Website Project

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, repository, many-to-one

I'm working on an MVC 3 website for a small business which has a database containing a few tables. There is a table for Products, a table for Feedback, and the table this question is about: Orders.

For placing orders, I have set up a shopping cart. When the user is ready to check out, they enter some info and arrange for a pickup date. This "Order" is then saved the database, where the Admin(s) can then see and respond to. I need to save the products from the shopping cart in a list, which will be contained in an entity called OrderInfo.

My question is, how can I set up a relationship between tables (foreign keys) to get a new table which associates OrderIDs with the Product entities that are on those orders?

Answer (score 0):

If you have tables like this:

```
create table Products
(
    pkProducts int not null primary key clustered,
    Name varchar(256) not null,
    ....
)

create table Orders
(
    pkOrders int not null primary key clustered,
    Name varchar(256) not null,
    ....
)
```

You would then create a join table that will house the many-to-many-relationship between Products and Orders:

```
create table OrderProduct
(
    fkOrders int foreign key references Orders (pkOrders),
    fkProducts int foreign key references Products (pkProducts)
)
```

If you wanted to get all products from a particular order (I used `Name` for the order, but you could use a more pertinent field for your domain logic):

```
select p.Name
from Products p
inner join OrderProduct op
on p.pkProducts = op.fkProducts
inner join Orders o
on o.pkOrders = op.fkOrders
where o.Name = 'Some Order Name'
```

Comment: That sounds about what I'm trying to do; do you by chance know how I could do this through the Visual Studio database (Server) explorer?

Comment: @ChrisV. I personally prefer to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to do all of my database development (DDL and DML), so I am not so verse with VS' database dev tools.  There's got to be a way to just open up a new query window within VS.  Then you can just copy, paste, and modify accordingly these `CREATE TABLE` batches.

Answer (score 0):

Do not save the products from the order in a single field as a list. Fields are supposed to be atomic, and it is bad form to store lists like this.

Instead, have a separate table called orderItem that stores each product in a separate row and maps them to the order they belong to via FK to the Order table.